# Create While and Focus

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop, android-edittext

It is a basic problem, the more accurate your help. I'm starting in programming Java / Android now.

Problem:

- I have an EditText (id = etnumx for the user enters the measure numx.)
- How to use a repetition structure so that as the value for numx > numy he ask the User to re-enter, highlighting the EditText (id = etnumx).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you question, you don't mention when the "numY" value is prone to change, so I'll just ignore that. But perhaps you could get an [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to take care of this task in the background of your application.

Here's something that could get you started :

```
if (numx > numy) {
    EditText mNumXEdit = (EditText) findViewById("etnumx");
    mNumXEdit.RequestFocus(); // focus the View

    // sends Toast notification to user in order to alert him he needs to take action
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "[ENTER MESSAGE]", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register to the edittext textchanged event and write your validation code there. if you find an error then call editText.focus()